# Take a picture in xamarin android but do not save image

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I'm trying to fire up an intent in Xamarin Android to take an image, I have used the code from their samples

```
private void TakeAPicture (object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent (MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
    App._file = new File (App._dir, String.Format("myPhoto_{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid()));
    intent.PutExtra (MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Uri.FromFile (App._file));
    StartActivityForResult (intent, 0);
}
```

However this would save a file to the phone. What I'd like to do is the same thing however just return the image in an `intent` or store it (temporarily) in the system just until I've handled the data.

It appears I may be looking for some implementation of the android `setClipData` but I can't seem to figure out how to get this working in Xamarin.

Any suggestions on how to edit the `PutExtra` line so I can get a ClipData URI as a result? My understanding is that once used the `GC` deletes the backend files in the ClipData fairly quickly.